# Change the current TabHost's Tab, inside a child Tab Activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I'm working on an Android Application where the `MainActivity` is a `TabActivity`, There are Three other `Activities :` `ACT1, ACT2 and ACT3` that are The `MainActivity` tabs, is it possible to change the `MainActivity` current tab inside `ACT1, ACT2 or ACT3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would essentially cast your reference to the parent to the actual class of the parent and then make a call to some public method that would do what you're looking to do.

here is an [example](http://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/two-way-communication-between-tabactivity-and-its-child-tabs/)